# React useState hook not updating array for removed item

Tags: reactjs, arrays, state, mdbtable

I have a react table that has a column with buttons, one to remove the row via `removeRow(idx)` callback. The handler correctly removes/filters out the corresponding row, however on subsequent attempts to remove more rows, the previously deleted row returns. Via the console logs, it appears React is not updating rowData even though the table shows a row being removed (albeit one at most). Every `console.log('rowData', rowData)` shows the original array.

I tried initializing the state to an empty array, but after some reworking, the `removeRow(idx)` function when clicked renders an empty table.

Anyone know what is going on here??

** UsersTable.js **

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import { MDBDatatable, MDBBtn, MDBIcon } from 'mdbReactUiKit';
import Wrapper from '../Wrapper';
import styled from 'styled-components';

import { rows, cols } from '../../variables/Users';

...

export default function UsersTable() {
  const [colData, setColData] = useState(cols)
  const [rowData, setRowData] = useState(addCustomButtons(rows))
  
  function addCustomButtons(rows) {
    return rows.map((row, idx) => {
      return {
        ...row,
        index: idx,
        email: (
          <StyledLink
            to='#'
            onClick={(e) => {
              window.location.href = `mailto:${row.emailraw}`;
              e.preventDefault();
            }}
          >
            {row.emailraw}
          </StyledLink>
        ),
        buttons: (
          <>
            <StyledButton
              size='sm'
              floating
              className='message-btn'
              onClick={() => console.log(`send a message to ${row.emailraw}`)}
            >
              <MDBIcon icon='envelope' />
            </StyledButton>
            <StyledButton outline size='sm' floating className='call-btn' onClick={() => console.log(`edit user settings`)}>
              <MDBIcon icon='ellipsis-h' />
            </StyledButton>
            <StyledTrash
              size='sm'
              floating
              className='remove-user-btn'
              onClick={() => removeRow(idx)}
            >
              <MDBIcon icon="trash" />
            </StyledTrash>
          </>
        ),
      };
    })
  }

// does not work
  const deleteRow = (index) => {
    if (rowData.length > 0) {
      var updatedRows = [...rowData]
      console.log('1st rowData', updatedRows)

      var indexToRemove = updatedRows.findIndex(x => x.index === index)
      console.log('remove', indexToRemove, index)

      if (indexToRemove > -1) {
        updatedRows.splice(indexToRemove, 1)
        var newRows = addCustomButtons(updatedRows)

        console.log(newRows)

        setRowData(newRows)
        // setTableData((prevState) => {
        //   return {
        //     ...prevState,
        //     rows: newRows
        //   }
        // })
      }
    }
  }

// almost works
  const removeRow = (index) => {
    console.log('rowData', rowData)
    const oldRows = [...rowData]
    const updatedRows = oldRows.filter((row) => row.index !== index);
    console.log('updated', updatedRows)

    setRowData(updatedRows)

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('timer', rowData)
    }, 3000)
  }


  const Table = ({ colData, rowData }) => {
    let tableData = {
      columns: colData,
      rows: rowData
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      tableData = {
        columns: colData,
        rows: rowData
      }
    }, [rowData])

  
    return (
      <StyledTable
        hover
        striped
  
        data={tableData}
        entriesOptions={[5, 10, 20]}
        entries={10}
  
        fixedHeader
        maxHeight='460px'
      />
    )
  }

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <TableContainer>
        <Table colData={colData} rowData={rowData} />
      </TableContainer>
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to change your `removeRow` function parameter (`index`) with a different name?

It might make the function not work since `row.index` will be `undefined`. So you could try something like:

```
    const removeRow = (indexRow) => {
       (row) => row.index !== indexRow)
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting the same output with rowData and timer print statements showing the original array